# Retrieve GANACHE address/publicKey Contracts/Transactions with PYTHON Web3 library

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py, ganache

In my dApp application, I would like to list the smart contracts that have been created by the logged-in 'user'. For instance, within the GANACHE blockchain, I've created several smart contracts that were created by different accounts (addresses). However, I want to display only the smart contracts created by the logged-in 'user'.

In the documentation, the closest thing I found to this was the 'get_transaction' attribute, but it requires the transaction ID/Hash as an argument, not the public key of the logged-in user.

Here's an example snippet of my code:

```
logged_pubkey = "0x5ffd9B1CF77DFb1FdDE505007a6F72A062503F77"
# Get the list of contracts (I know that if this worked I would need an for loop to retrieve all the data, this was just a test)
transactions = w3.eth.get_transaction()
# I need a for loop to filter the contracts created by the logged-in user
print(transactions)
```

Is there a way to retrieve the smart contracts created by a specific user based on their public key in GANACHE or any other suggestions on how to achieve this functionality?